# Application of Geometric Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What number must  be added to each of -2, 4, 19 so that the resulting numbers are 3 terms of a geometric sequence?

Comment: Are the 3 terms consecutive?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You're looking for numbers $a$, $c$, and $r$ such that
$$\begin{align*}-2+a&=c,\\
4+a&=cr,\\
19+a&=cr^2.\end{align*}$$
Note that if $a$, $c$, and $r$ satisfy these relations, then
$$c(r-1)=6$$
and
$$cr(r-1)=15.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the number be $a$. Then $-2+a, 4+a, 19+a$ is such that $(4+a)^2=(-2+a)(19+a)$. Solve the equaiton giving $a=6$.

Comment: why is it (4+a)^2?

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx I assume that the 3 terms stated are the consecutive term in a geometric sequence. For any 3 consecutive terms $a, b$ and $c$ in a geometric sequence, we have the common ratio is $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$ and hence $b^2=ac$

Comment: Why did I get a -6 instead of a positive? I am sure I did everything correctly and I know that your answer is correct. Can you show me how does that happened?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't state that they must be consecutive terms in a geometric sequence, so while the two solutions posted thus far are very nice, the door is open to more exotic answers as well.

For instance, if we suppose $-2+a=c$, $4+a=cr^2$ and $19+a=cr^3$, then
$$(4+a)^3=(19+a)^2(-2+a)$$
which has solutions
$$a=\frac{1}{16}\left(-79\pm 15\sqrt{65}\right).$$